# Оптимизация чтения из serial порта python

Tags: python, pyserial

суть вопроса: есть две сущности:

1. STM32 которая постоянно отправляет данные с датчиков в serial порт
2. OrangePi который читает данные из serial порта, проблема в том что когда я пытаюсь ЗАПИСАТЬ данные из serial порта, это занимает 1 секунду (чтение + присвоение), что очень плохо сказывается на работе устройства. Вот код

```
    def read_data(self):
        raw_data = self.serial_port.readline().decode('utf-8')
        values = raw_data.split('|')
        if len(values) == 2:
            try:
                value = float(values[self.number - 1])
                # print(f"{self.number}: {value}")
                return value
            except ValueError:
                print(f"[ INFO ] Ошибка чтения данных")
        else:
            print(f"[ INFO ] Некорректный формат данных: {raw_data}")

        return None
```

UPD: Накрыл тестами, оказалось что запись занимает так много времени, а не чтение, как быть?

Comment: Нужны треды или асинхронная читалка